# be supposed to have read it

Tags: grammar

A)you are not supposed to have read it

B)you were not supposed to read it

C)you were not supposed to have read it

are three of these sentences in the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

A. (Speaking of the present time) you have read it even though you did not have permission to do so.

C. (In the past) you had read it even though you had not had permission.

B. (In the past) you did not have permission to read it.